# debug assertion error when using findcontour function of opencv with kinect 2

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect, kinect-sdk

I want to use `kinect sdk 2.0` with `opencv` for shape detection. for that i want to get contour of for the image frame. But i am getting assertion error when I use `findcontour` function of `opencv`.

here is the code I used:

```
void Kinect::ProcessColor(RGBQUAD* pBuffer, int nWidth, int nHeight)
{
    // Make sure we've received valid data
    if (pBuffer && (nWidth == cColorWidth) && (nHeight == cColorHeight))
    {
        // Draw the data with OpenCV
        Mat ColorImage(nHeight, nWidth, CV_8UC4, pBuffer);      
        //Mat ColorImage;
        //ColorImage = imread("C:/Users/IWP/Desktop/Untitled.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

        //imshow("ColorImage", ColorImage);

        // Convert it to gray
        Mat src_gray;
        cvtColor(ColorImage, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);    

        // Canny
        Mat src_canny;
        Canny(src_gray, src_canny, 75, 125, 3);
        //threshold(src_gray, src_canny, 128, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

        // find the contours
        vector< vector<Point> > contours;
        findContours(src_canny, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

        Mat showImage;
        resize(src_canny, showImage, Size(nWidth / 2, nHeight / 2));
        imshow("ColorImage", showImage);////imshow("ColorImage", ColorImage);
    }
}
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: please check your linker settings. strictly use opencv debug libs for a debug build and release ones for a release build.

Comment: if i don't use findcontour, i can get rgb stream , but when i am using findcontour function, it gives assertion error.
So, linker setting forr opencv is okay in this case

Comment: you don't understand the problem. as soon as you're using anything from c++ stdlib, like a std::vector, or a std::string, you will run into above problem, if you got the libs wrong, so please go and check this again.

Comment: i have checked libs , it's fine